# How to prove $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}+ \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq 4 $ using Middle School methods?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How to prove this:

> $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}+ \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq 4 $$

(Sorry I've asked this question on phone.)

I can understand the C-S step, but I've never learnt about the Schur inequality... I have googled it but I have no idea how to apply it here :/

I've done it by using harmonic mean to the Schur

Comment: are $a,b,c$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Yes they're. And thanks for editing it! :)

Comment: (i don't think people write "they're" to shorten "they are" in this circumstance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step:

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+ac+bc}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+ac+bc}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq4,$$
which is true and the proof for you.

Comment: I can understand the C-S step, but I've never learnt about the Schur inequality... I have googled it but I have no idea how to apply it here :/

Comment: @Blate Raven The Schur inequality is the following. For all positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\geq0.$ Try to use it.

Comment: I've done it by using harmonic mean to the Schur.